# Forloop count isn't defined in JS?

Tags: javascript

Tried doing this for a class assignment but for whatever reason it is saying the count is not defined. Any suggestions?

```
var num = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for(var num = 0; count < 11; num++) {
if(num % 3 ===0);
console.log(num);
}
```

Comment: `num < 11` instead of `count < 11`. I vote to close this.

Comment: you may decide if you iterate an array with an index or just use a counter and use the value of it.

Comment: `count` is not defined as a variable

Comment: What is the expected result? You define `num` as an array, but then you never use the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to use the num variable instead of count.

```
for(var num = 0; num < 11; num++) {
```

You are defining the 'num' variable. Setting it to 0 and then running the 'for' loop, adding 1 to 'num' for each loop until 'num' is no longer < 11.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```js
var num = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
for (var count = 0; count < num.length; count++) {
  if (num[count] % 3 == 0)
    alert(num[count]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, Javascript for loops will have this format:

```
for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    //i = 0  > starting index
    //i < 11 > ending index
    //i++    > index increment 
}
```

The reason why you ran into your error is because count is never defined as a variable, whereas the variable 'i' in my example was defined when I set the value of i=0.

Instead of thinking that you are looping through the integers within the num array, think of it like you're looping through the ***indexes*** of num. So within every loop, the i variable will represent which index of the array you're currently focusing on.

Helpful tips:

- make sure you utilize num.length to get the ending index of your for loop
- Use indexes to reference integers in an array: num[0] == 1,
  num[1] == 2, num[2] == 3 ...